# Remover um atributo do elemento <a> quando houver um atributo específico - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

No HTML da página que estou ajustando, contém vários links com uma função no evento do `onClick`:

```
<a href='#' onClick='funcao(100)'>Link</a>
```

e o Javascript atual está assim:

```
<script>
function funcao(numero) {
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "url-checka-numero/",
        data: { numero: numero },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.return').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Tentei desativar o `onClick` do elemento `<a>` ao clicar nele:

```
<script>
function funcao(numero) {
$(this).removeAttr('onClick');
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "url-checka-numero/",
        data: { numero: numero },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.return').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

A intenção é excluir apenas o `onClick` dos elementos `<a>` que contém o `onclick='funcao(n)'`, e não os outros, mas o que fiz remove tudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você consegue usar a função **attr**, da seguinte forma, segue a [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

O **removeAttr**, tem alguns problemas para ser executado em alguns browsers, para evitar complicações leve como costume usar a função **attr** ou **prop** para essas funções.

```
$(this).attr("onclick", null);
```

Comment: @henriqueepedro, boa noite, o onclick será nulo, e depois na resposta 'success' do $.ajax tem como recuperar o que havia antes fazendo desse modo?

Comment: Tem sim, cria uma variável para guardar esse valor, colocar essa variável no inicio da função, **var onclick = $(this).attr("onclick")**

Comment: Mas não resolveria, pois cada onclick='function(n)' tem um valor diferente, e deveria anular todos, para que não haja duplo clique ou outro clique em outros elementos <a> senão gerará uma compra dupla, tem usuário que não espera a resposta do servidor e fica clicando rs, mas se não houver tudo bem, vou manter assim até encontrar um meio de contornar isso, obg.

Comment: Entendi, nesse caso teria que usar um each em todos os link, que teria que usar um id em cada link e guardar em um array o id do link e o atributo do onlick, ou como eu uso que acho mais simples pelo fato de ter o atributo disabled, seria usar button e ao iniciar a execução de uma função atribuir disabled para todos os buttons e no final da função remover.

Comment: Oi, resolveu do jeito que você disse, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode passar o elemento que foi clicado como parâmetro para sua função, tente assim:

```
<script>
function funcao(numero, el) {
    $(el).removeAttr('onClick');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "url-checka-numero/",
        data: { numero: numero },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.return').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

E no HTML, atualize para:

```
<a href='#' onClick='funcao(100, this)'>Link</a>
```

Segue um exemplo do que você precisa funcionando: https://codepen.io/tkrempser/pen/GawNaZ

Comment: Obrigado pela sua sapiência, vou testar também, outro modo de fazer vai ajudar para outros ajustes que vi.